# Excel Formula Meaning of $

Tags: excel

what the meaning of this formula?

```
=B9/$G$3
```

Actually i didn't understand what the meaning of `$` sign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an [absolute reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-formulas-HP010081865.aspx#BMusing_references_in_formulas): it means don't treat this as a relative reference if you copy / paste. If you copy that into the cell below to it, you'll get

```
=B10/$G$3
```

i.e. Excel has automatically updated the row in the formula for the new location of B9->10, but left G3 alone - i.e. it's a constant you've set once that you want to apply to all rows or cells in a table.

Comment: Highlighting the reference(s) and pressing [F4] will cycle through the relative references automatically for those references highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

The `$` tells Excel not to change the number / character that comes after it when you extend the selection.

If you put that formula in `D5`, then fill it down to `E5`, it will become `C9/$G$3`.
The `G` doesn't change to `H` because the `$` tells it not to.