# want to know the difference between D7, $D7 and $D$7

Tags: excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel Formula Meaning of $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984282/excel-formula-meaning-of)

I'm new to the excel macro development, can anyone tell me the difference between D7, $D7 and $D$7?

Comment: @David: I agree with JMax. The link which Jmax gave should answer your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D7 is a relative reference. If you write formula =D7 in cell A1, then copy and paste to cell A2 the formula in A2 will be =D8.

$D$7 is an absolute reference. Copy and paste it anywhere you like. It will always refer to D7.
Good use for this is a constant that will be referred to by many other cells.

$D7 is an absolute column, relative row. So you can refer to column D from any other other column on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

The $ sign indicates fixation of either column or row so that in a table you can enter a formula always pointing to the same cell $D$7 or column $D7 or row D$7.
The cells without $ will autoincrement according to the place you copy the formula to.