# Excel formula needs to be dragged to a column not adjacent to it (reference cells should change accordingly)

Tags: excel, drag, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet where one column is filled with forlmulae that link it to other cells. Say Column R is linked to values in columns I through L.
Column T is to have a similar relation with Columns M through P as Column R had with Columns I through L. 
I could drag the formula but there is another cell in between that I do not want to disturb.

Is there any way I can copy the formulae from the column R and paste them in column T ?

Comment: CTRL C to copy and CTRL V to paste? Excel will automatically update references in Col T

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Formula Meaning of $](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984282/excel-formula-meaning-of)

Comment: @JMAX- No, this is not regarding the constant reference ($), in fact it is just the opposite, I wanted the reference to change, but the presence of a column between the original formula and the target column was the cause of the confusion. The problem is now resolved, thanks for the time

Comment: Yes that worked, stupid question! I hadn't tried it thinking that It would copy paste the formula as it is with the same references! Thanks a lot for the time and help @Siddharth, apologies for my blunder!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change column, you should write in formula a '$' char before column name.

For example:

```
B1 = A1 + C1
```

You don't want to change column C write:

```
B1 = A1 + $C1
```

But if you don't want to change cell C1, write:

```
B1 = A1 + $C$1
```