# copy and paste formula with constant cell

Tags: excel

I need to make Total_Price calculation of working hours:

Excel sheet looks this way:

```
Job_name(A1);Time_spend(B1);Total_Price(C1);
```

And I have hour price in special constant cell - `F1`.

To get Total_Price I'm using formula =B1*F1. After this I copy cell and paste into all rest cells in C column manually. According this procedure C2 gets formula =B2*F2, but I need =B2*F1.

How to make this procedure more automatic?

Comment: Try using `=B1*$F$1`

Comment: kind of duplicate of [Excel Formula Meaning of $](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984282/excel-formula-meaning-of)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use absolute referencing. Instead of `=B1*F1` use:

```
=B1*$F$1
```

Adding the `$` signs in front of the cell references prevents the reference from changing as you drag the formula.

Comment: ...as per comment from 2 hours earlier - might be an idea to acknowledge this in future :)

Comment: Sorry Lori, (I gave you a +1) I can snipe answers less, but you should submit answers down here instead of in the comments! :]

Comment: That's ok, i'm not too bothered about rep - more interested in finding the right solution to a given problem. This question should be migrated to SuperUser anyway.